# Egress requirements for a bedroom with two doors

Tags: egress

Do I need an egress window in a home office that could be used as a bedroom if there are two doors on opposite ends of the room, neither of which opens to the outside. This is in a single story house without a basement.

Comment: I should add, it has a fairly large double hung window without equal sashes that does not open 24" vertically.

Comment: Which Jurisdiction / Country are you in?

Comment: If each door leads to a separate way outside, it might be okay.  If each door leads to same way(up the same set of stairs), probably not.

Answer (score 1):

The egress (Emergency Escape and Rescue Opening) requirement is **to the outside**. (Open **directly** to a public way, or to a yard or court that opens to a public way) https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018P7/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018P7_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310

So, yes, you need an egress **to the outside** - can be a door, can be a window. Or you need to convince your LAHJ that it's not a sleeping room.

The exceptions involve sprinkers and basements, so they don't appear to apply here.